# Java: System.out and System.err output to the same stream?

Tags: java

When using `System.out.println` or `System.err.println` what is the difference? In a console app they seems to be practically the same.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: For starters, when using netbeans, `System.err` is red.

Comment: Well, I use eclipse, but is that standard? I don't think tthat I can expect every console to manage red output this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is clearly defined here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

There are also methods defined (which you will find in this document) for how to change these streams (System.setErr, System.setOut, System.setIn)

Comment: +1 for the link to the API docs. For completeness, here are the docs for Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html. (Of course, this part of the System class hasn't changed, so it's probably not an issue.)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is defined in the underlying operating system. By default both of these streams are sent to the console (i.e. your monitor). However, a user can redirect them independently. For example in a Unix-like environment, `java MyClass > output.txt` will redirect `System.out` to the file `output.txt`, but anything sent to `System.err` will still go to the console. For more details, you can google for `stdout` and `stderr`; these are the typical names for these streams on most operating systems.

Comment: Shell redirection is different from setting the streams to which System.(out|in|err) use.

Comment: @WillC. Perhaps I should have specified that these are the defaults. I didn't know that you can set the streams programmatically in Java. I've never done that and even after seeing the other answers question the usefulness of doing so.

Comment: Well, I tried shell redirects to send the output to a text file, and both sysouts were sent to a text file

Comment: What about err sent to log files or something?

Comment: @Code-Guru The usefulness of setting the output streams at runtime is so that there is a consistent stream being written to for all systems executing your byte code.

Comment: Redirection sends all output to that stream to the same location. Some systems are configured to redirect System.err to a log file.

Comment: @WillC. Sounds reasonable. I don't have any experience with large projects running on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is the standard output and `System.err` is the error output.

- Some IDE Consoles show the `System.out` in standard font and `System.out` in red color.
- A Java web server would send the err and out to two different files.
- Using the command line `java -jar yourjar.jar >out.txt 2>err.txt` would send `System.out` to `out.txt` and `System.err` to `err.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everyone else here has said since they are two separate streams, interleaving of threads in a concurrent system could cause the print order to surprise you if you use them interchangeably. It just depends on how the operating system prioritizes them when telling the processor what to do.